# Is there a way to change the language of an embedded Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, localization, embed

I'm embedded a Google Map in my website and it always appears in the user's browser locale language, whereas I want it to always be in English.

Is there any way to enforce this?

Here's an example:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Add the optional parameter `language` to the request URL:

https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/MODE?key=API_KEY&language=en

See the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters) for further information.